# 4 lines records into one line? How to combine in a single line?

Tags: r

I would like to ask you for help. I have data looking like this: (one record is in four lines:

```
 9540    16
0.1586E-03-0.3713E-04 0.1559E-03-0.4054E-04 0.2610E-02 0.2589E-03 0.4509E-03
0.7271E-03 0.2286E-03 0.8627E-03 0.1511E-02 0.1208E-03 0.1169     0.5486E-01
0.1419E-01 0.1715    
 9546    16
0.1546E-03-0.2273E-04 0.1504E-03-0.1516E-04 0.2517E-02 0.1968E-03 0.5512E-03
0.7556E-03 0.2998E-03 0.1024E-02 0.1495E-02 0.6889E-03 0.1134     0.5461E-01
0.1418E-01 0.1708
```

I would like to read this into R and look like this (in one line):

```
9540 16 0.1586E-03 -0.3713E-04 0.1559E-03 -0.4054E-04 0.2610E-02 0.2589E-03 0.4509E-03 0.7271E-03 0.2286E-03 0.8627E-03 0.1511E-02 0.1208E-03 0.1169   0.5486E-01 0.1419E-01 0.1715    
9546 16 0.1546E-03 -0.2273E-04 0.1504E-03 -0.1516E-04 0.2517E-02 0.1968E-03 0.5512E-03 0.7556E-03 0.2998E-03 0.1024E-02 0.1495E-02 0.6889E-03 0.1134     0.5461E-01 0.1418E-01 0.1708
```

Answer (score 0):

We could read the file using `readLines`.  Create a grouping variable using `gl`,  `paste` the 'lines' based on the group with `tapply`.  If needed, we can remove the leading and lagging spaces with `str_trim` from `library(stringr)`

```
lines <- readLines('fourlines.txt')
lines2 <- tapply(lines, as.numeric(gl(length(lines), 4, length(lines))), 
                 FUN= paste, collapse=' ')
library(stringr)    
lines2 <- str_trim(unname(lines2))
```

Output of 'lines2'

```
lines2
#[1] "9540    16 0.1586E-03-0.3713E-04 0.1559E-03-0.4054E-04 0.2610E-02 0.2589E-03 0.4509E-03 0.7271E-03 0.2286E-03 0.8627E-03 0.1511E-02 0.1208E-03 0.1169     0.5486E-01 0.1419E-01 0.1715"
#[2] "9546    16 0.1546E-03-0.2273E-04 0.1504E-03-0.1516E-04 0.2517E-02 0.1968E-03 0.5512E-03 0.7556E-03 0.2998E-03 0.1024E-02 0.1495E-02 0.6889E-03 0.1134     0.5461E-01 0.1418E-01 0.1708"
```

If we want to remove the extra spaces

```
lines2 <- gsub('\\s+', ' ', lines2)
```